# Is there an autocmd or some other hook to detect when `wrap` or `textwidth` is toggled/set?

Tags: vim

I have a function that lets me cycle through different wrap states, setting a bunch of options (e.g., `formatoptions`, remapping of `0`, `$`, and other linewise movements etc.) depending on whether wrapping is off (`set nowrap` and `set textwidth=0`) soft (`set wrap` and `set textwidth=0`), or hard (`set textwidth=78`).

This all works fine *if* wrap-state is set by going through the function.

If not though (e.g., if a third-party plugin sets the wrap state), then these options/mappings do not get set/reset.

Is there a way for me to handle these events if they are triggered by other code? That is, whenever `wrap` or `textwidth` is changed, a function (or command) gets called to adjust key-maps and options accordingly?

*[Note: edited for clarity]*

Comment: It is not very clear from the question, why do not just *get* current state of options when your function invoked instead of handling every changing. Anyway, a good question. And, as far as now, the answer is negative – there is no such hook.

Comment: The problem is that my function is *not* invoked when the wrap mode is changed externally, and then I have to manually invoke my function to make everything OK. So, e.g., on opening a document some plugin sets `set wrap`. But all my key-maps and options etc. are still in the default `no wrap` mode (e.g., `j` is not mapped to `gj`, `formatoptions` wrong). I have to then call my function myself (usually after realizing that things are not working the way I want them to. I want to avoid the need for me to manually invoke my own function, instead triggering whenever `wrap` and `textwidth` change.

Answer (score 2):

There's no `OptionChanged` or so event; best you can do is using a set of events that is triggered frequently, e.g. `CursorHold,CursorHoldI,CursorMoved,CursorMovedI`. If you store the previous value of the option and compare it with the current one, you can find out whether it got changed.

Comment: Of course, you don't want to do anything too slow in an autocmd that uses those events, since they are triggered so often.

Comment: @EvergreenTree: Yes, basically just compare and return. To decouple this from the actual code that reacts to it, you could fire an `:doautocmd User` event.